# How can I change the color for each event?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

well, I want to set a different color for each event. Basically that's it
I'm reading events from an Ajax call
Thanks

EDIT: I don't want to wait **8 hours** for answer my own question

first of all, my apologize for not include code example on my answer, but thanks to Brandom who guide me to find my answer :P

So, here is my .js file which has an Ajax call to my events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: {
        url:'http://myhost/mysite/ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{ trigger: 'eventos' },
        error: function() { alert('there was an error while fetching events!'); }
      }
    });
}
```

then, in my .php file who receives my ajax call I have this:

```
<?
 if($_POST['trigger'] == 'eventos'){
     $eventos = new WP_Query();
     $eventos->query(array(
         'post_type' => 'evento'
         )
      );
     $eventdata = array();
     while($eventos->have_posts()) : $eventos->the_post();
        $elem = array(
          'id' => $post->ID,
          'title' => $post->post_title,
          'start' => get('evento_fecha_inicio',1,1,$post->ID),
          'end' => get('evento_fecha_termino',1,1,$post->ID),
          'allDay' => 'false',
          'color' => '#'.rand(000000,999999), //this is what I'm was looking for!
        );
        $eventdata[] = $elem;
     endwhile;

     echo json_encode($eventdata);
 }
?>
```

(the 'get' functions corresponds to [magicfields](http://magicfields.org/)' functions). So there it is, with a rand(); in the color value I can generate a random color for each event element

(sorry for my english)

Comment: As written, your question makes no sense. Please provide a LOT more specifics.

Comment: Yeah...... I think you have to provide way more information and code for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: The question could use some code, but it does seem to make sense. He just wants to change the colors of the events on the FullCalendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FullCalendar v1.5 you can set the `color`, `backgroundColor`, `borderColor` and `textColor` properties of the [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: Why any plugin developer would create something called an "event object" when JavaScript already has a completely different event object is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

hard to know what you're trying to achieve here,

but maybe something of the following?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/test.html",
    success:function(data){
        $("#colored-div").css("background", data);
    }
});
```

Again I'm going blindly with what you want to achieve, please provide more details if you need further help...